# HTML print text from a txt file with styles

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to print text file contents into an HTML page using either `<object>` or `<embed>` and trying to add styles onto the output.

I've tried both:

```
<object width="700" height="30" type="text/plain" data="title.txt" border="2"></object>
```

and:

```
<embed src="title.txt" width="700" height="36">
```

with a style header of:

```
<style> 
object {font-size: 50px; font-family: Arial;}
embed {font-size: 50px; font-family: Arial;}
</style>
```

If it's not possible to style output text from these methods, is there any other way text files could be displayed?

Comment: I think you would have to resort to Javascript in such a case.

Comment: @barhatsor How would I do so? Would I have to install anything as well?